# Images not updating in heroku app running on angular and node

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku

I am running angular-7 app with back-end of node. I am updating home logo through back-end but it is not reflecting on UI. I am doing fs.rename to rename the uploaded file with the name of home logo image file and rename is successful but still image is not updated on UI.

Comment: Why are you renaming the file on backend instead of deploying the file with the correct name from start?

Comment: Actually any user can choose his/her home logo in our app, so we need to update the home logo on runtime

Comment: Well, you can't solve the problem by changing the image name on backend since Heroku Dynos have an ephemeral filesystem (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). You could request a different file from the Angular app on frontend, instead? What I am trying to say is that you can't upload file on the Dyno fs, basically

Comment: Actually our old app was running on angular-js and in that we were doing the same thing and it was working fine. So, ideally it should also work with angular.